Hide curve fit line in spotfire using ironpython
I would like to create regression curve fit in a scatterplot and then set it to separate fit for each color, trellis and shape. But I would like to hide/disable the line for one of the shapes alone - is that doable with ironpython code - I am not familiar enough with spotfire API to pull this off
I can interact with basic curve fit options through ironpython scripting
